# Accept textbox value when its first letter is an alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, jquery

Accept text box value when it's first letter is  a alphanumeric .
In my html page i have a text box, which has to accept only alphanumeric .If first letter is integer truncate.for special chatacter also.

```
<input  type="text"  onKeyUp="numericFilter(this);"/>

function numericFilter(txb) {
  txb.value = txb.value.replace(/[^\0-9]/ig, "");
}
```

Above code only accept integer only how can i change it.

Comment: Before we answer that, can you explain what you think that code in `numericFilter` does? Because that's important: if you can explain what it does, you can already answer your own question here.

Comment: the code will replace with " " when text box contain non integer value..
i need regexp  for my requirement

Comment: no it doesn't. Look at `/[^\0-9]/ig` again, and tell us what that does.

Comment: i don't know. i'm new to regular expression.

Comment: That's not a good enough answer. Find out what it does. I'll give you https://www.debuggex.com/ as a hint, but you need to do your research/learning so that you understand what you're asking about before stackoverflow's here to help you. "I used this code, I don't know what it does, please help" is going to get the kind of help that goes "educate yourself, we'll see you after that"

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateQuestionNo(txb){
    var QNO_REGEX = new RegExp(/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$/i);
    var qNo=txb.value;
     if (!qNo.match(QNO_REGEX)) {
         txb.value ='';
         }

}
```

found my answer.
@  Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans  thanks for ur support.